# Is there a way to program 100% object-oriented in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

I guess, it's possible to call functions in a separate class, I call this object-oriented programming in PHP.

But at the beginning, there is always an index.php or something, which calls or instantiates another class.

Is there a way at all to have a class which is self-calling in a way like java does with

```
public static void main(String[] args) ...
```

Comment: Your example is precisely the least OOP part of Java...

Comment: What is 100% OOP? Is there such a thing as 50% OOP?

Comment: Yes, there is ;) for example, if you use classes and such, but in every class you just have a method `doWork()` and in there you just have your orders from top to down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not by default. But you could write your own *bootstrap* that does this, [see a related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800167/where-do-i-place-include-once-in-a-php-app/8800230#8800230) that outlines how you can do it.

If `index.php` is your only central entry point, it's already the bootstrap.

From that point on, you can do everything OOP you like. However, I think your question is less about OOP but more about how you deal with the invokation of your application code.

Answer (score 2):

You need an entry point into your application *somewhere*. Java's entry point happens to be a predefined named location which is automatically called when an app starts. PHP's entry point is the first line of the first file that executes. As such, you need to get the ball rolling with a single "procedural" call somewhere, which could simply be something like:

```
require_once 'controller.php';
new Controller;
```

That's essentially the same thing Java does, just more explicitly.