# Is there a PHP equivalent for `public static main(String[] args)` in Java?

Tags: php, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to program 100% object-oriented in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800397/is-there-a-way-to-program-100-object-oriented-in-php)

What I am trying to accomplish would look something like this:

```
 <?php
      //index.php
      class Site{
           public static function main(){
                // starts all the processing of the site
           }
      }
 ?>
```

So that when someone visits the site's `index.php` the site will start up without having any code outside the class.

Yes I know that I could use `__autoload` or even `spl_autoload_register` to handle autoloading of classes but that would still most likely need to be added outside of the class.

I have my doubts that this is possible but I don't know why this wouldn't be possible.

Comment: Why would you ever need an entry point in php???

Comment: @deceze yes that looks like it might meet my question's requirements, however as often as I searched it never appeared in the results. It could be I was using the wrong information in my search.

Comment: Yes there is...

public function __construct()  {  /* Do Something on object construction */ }

Answer (score 32, accepted):

No.

Java's entry point is defined as the `main` method. PHP's entry point is defined as the first line in the first file that gets executed. You *will* have to start with "procedural" code.

Comment: Thanks for the direct answer. I've been puzzling this in my head for the last two days, while searching for possible direct answers to this question. I guess I need more practice with my SO search criteria since you found a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your Site class like that and make that class construct everything, but you'd still need an entry file to initialize the class. You could 'boot up' your site with one line in your index file. Doesn't seem like a big inhibitor of flexibility.

So, answer would be no :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such concept out of the box with php. You will have to have something either in index.php or something in an .htaccess file that will redirect the user to the file you want, but the class will always have to be instanced by code